# Android Device Not Receiving GCM Notifications from Amazon SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

We are moving our notification service from our servers to SNS.
We have followed up AWS documentation.
We were able to setup iOS notifications successfully.

But when sending to android nothing is received on the device.
We have setup the application using the same key on our live server currently, we added an endpoint using a device hash that is active on the devices databases.
We are trying to send the messages from SNS panel, but nothing is received on our android device!

What could we be missing to setup a working GCM with Amzon SNS?

Comment: Try turn on SNS delivery status. See http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxHTXGC8711JNF/Using-the-Delivery-Status-feature-of-Amazon-SNS

Comment: already did that, no failures shown, just Notification not received on the device

Comment: Nothing wrong in the delivery status log? Can your device receive GCM from other apps?

Comment: yes we can receive successfully, but not from SNS

Comment: GCM is much more complicated than FCM. Why you didn't migrate project already?

Answer (score 1):

Use a notification payload with a body, instead of a data payload. Here is the JSON:

```
{
 "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"Hey. Just saying hi.\" } }"
}
```